# Backup Failed - Deja Dup

Tags: 18.04, python, backup, deja-dup

Last few days I've been trying to make a new backup on Deja Dup but I get the error:

```
Backup Failed

Failed with an unknown error.

Traceback (innermost last):

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
    do_backup(action)

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1523, in do_backup
    incremental_backup(sig_chain)

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 668, in incremental_backup
    globals.backend)

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 454, in write_multivol
    (tdp, dest_filename, vol_num)))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 146, in schedule_task
    return self.__run_synchronously(fn, params)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/asyncscheduler.py", line 172, in __run_synchronously
    ret = fn(*params)

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 453, in <lambda>
    vol_num: put(tdp, dest_filename, vol_num),

File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 342, in put
    backend.put(tdp, dest_filename)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 395, in inner_retry
    % (n, e.__class__.__name__, util.uexc(e)))

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/util.py", line 79, in uexc
    return ufn(unicode(e).encode('utf-8'))
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Despite it showing the above error Deja Dup now says 'Last backup was today' though if I go into recovery the only backups available to recover are a few months old or more - from the last time I backed up.

Deja Dup version 37.0 running on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
I'm trying to backup to an external drive (not a remote google drive) - which does have sufficient free volume on it.

My issue seems to be the same as here: [Deja dup backup fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113370/deja-dup-backup-fails)
Which was never resolved.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: Try the snap or flatpak release (both on 40.6).

Comment: I'm having the same issue...